# Adventure 3 ABS problems with raft and quality

Tags: print-quality, abs, flashforge, flashforge-adventurer-3

So I started using ABS yesterday, I have done multiple prints and the quality was amazing to start with, but now I'm getting small protrusions out of the layers. I use the FlashPrint fine settings for ABS.

But I am also having issues with the raft. The first layer doesn’t actually get put down and the ABS is trying to be forced into the nozzle and it makes a hell of a sound, but the second layer goes down quite easily. Now I have recalibrated the bed multiple times and the 0.1 mm change in the nozzle height during the calibration causes it to go from one extreme to the other as it spews out in an inconsistent thickness causing the nozzle to then hit the 2nd layer as it prints the next. I'm guessing the slight bumps in the raft may cause a drop in quality.

There are no issues with adhesion. It sticks very well annoyingly.
And there are no issues with peeling.

Any tips?

Sorry for the long read, not good at explaining.

Comment: Hi Blake, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Why not add a photograph? Pictures say more than words.